# Datetime column coerced to int when setting with .loc and slice

Tags: pandas, datetime, slice

I have a column of datetimes and need to change several of these values to new datetimes. When I set the values using df.loc[indices, 'col'] = new_datetimes, the unaffected values are coerced to int while the new set values are in datetime. If I set the values one at a time, no type coercion occurs.

For illustration I created a sample df with just one column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([dt.datetime(2019,1,1)]*5)
df.loc[[1,3,4]] = [dt.datetime(2019,1,2)]*3
df
```

This produces the following:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doawf.png)

If I change indices 1,3,4 individually:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([dt.datetime(2019,1,1)]*5)
df.loc[1] = dt.datetime(2019,1,2)
df.loc[3] = dt.datetime(2019,1,2)
df.loc[4] = dt.datetime(2019,1,2)
df
```

I get the correct output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIczC.png)

A suggestion was to turn the list to a numpy array before setting, which does resolve the issue. However, if you try to set multiple columns (some of which are not datetime) using a numpy array, The issue arises again.

In this example the dataframe has two columns and I try to set both columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':[dt.datetime(2019,1,1)]*5, 'value':[1,1,1,1,1]})
df.loc[[1,3,4]] = np.array([[dt.datetime(2019,1,2)]*3, [2,2,2]]).T
df
```

This gives the following output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvMGg.png)

Can someone please explain what is causing the coercion and how to prevent it from doing so? The code I wrote that uses this was written over a month ago and used to work just fine, could it be one of those warnings about future version of pandas deprecating certain functionalities?

An explanation of what is going on would be greatly appreciated because I wrote a other codes that likely employ similar functionality want to make sure everything works as intended.

Comment: Based off the suggestions I tried setting using a dataframe instead of list/array and it set both columns without coercion.

`df.loc[[1,3,4]] = pd.DataFrame({'dt':[dt.datetime(2019,1,1)]*3, 'value':[2,2,2]}, index=[1,3,4])`

I guess I will go back to the code I wrote and convert all the arrays to dataframes before setting. Does anyone know the reason for coercion when not using dataframes?

Comment: You assigning values in way that you don't have to. ```df.loc[[1,3,4]] = dt.datetime(2019,1,2), 2``` Returns your correct output with no changes. With .loc there is no need to match the length of the input if they are all going to change to the same output.

Comment: Second thing: 1546300800000000000 is actually the representation of 2019/1/1 as an int. ```pd.to_datetime(1546300800000000000)``` you can see converts it back to its datetime format. It converted it to an object due to the way you set it, and converted the dt to the int version.

Comment: I guess i should have made the sample more complicated. For convenience, i set the same values to the three rows, but in the real application the rows are different.

I'm aware of the fact that the int is actually representing the datetime. What is confusing me is why df.loc[1,3,4] = array causes the coercion while df.loc[1,3,4] = dataframe type does not.

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by *w-m* has such an "awkward detail" than
the result column has also the **time part** (it didn't have it
before).

I have also such a remark, that DataFrames are **tables** not **Series**,
so they have columns, each with its name and it is a bad habit to
rely on default column names (consecutive numbers).

So I propose another solution, addressing both above issues:

To create the source DataFrame I executed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1)]*5, columns=['c1'])
```

Note that I provided a name for the only column.

Then I created **another** DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([dt.datetime(2019,1,2)]*3, columns=['c1'], index=[1,3,4])
```

It contains your "new" dates and the numbers which you used in *loc*
I set as the **index** (again with the same column name).

Then, to update *df*, use (not surprisingly) *df.update*:

```
df.update(df2)
```

This function performs in-place update, so if you *print(df)*, you will get:

```
          c1
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-02
2 2019-01-01
3 2019-01-02
4 2019-01-02
```

As you can see, under indices 1, 3 and 4 you have new dates
and there is **no time part**, just like before.

Comment: Setting using a dataframe worked. I'm not really concerned about the time part. The issue was that it turned my column of datetimes into a column of integers and datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

`[dt.datetime(2019,1,2)]*3` is a Python list of objects. This particular list happens to contain only datetimes, but Pandas does not seem to recognize that, and treats it as it is - a list of any kind of objects.

If you convert it into a typed array, then Pandas will keep the original dtype of the column intact:

```
df.loc[[1,3,4]] = np.asarray([dt.datetime(2019,1,2)]*3)
```

I hope this workaround helps you, but you may still want to file a bug with Pandas. I don't have an explanation as to why the datetime objects should be coerced to ints in the first output example.

Comment: Thanks, turning it into an array does work if I'm only changing the datetime column. The problem is that in the actual code, I'm setting multiple columns (one of which is datetime) using a numpy array. I will update the question to include this case.